# unwanted Space between table rows

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the little space between the rows to close.

The space did decrease after using border-collapse: collapse; but there is still a tiny bit left.

```css
table {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.text-container {
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 1440px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="img-container">
      <img src="images/image-product-desktop.jpg" alt="image-product-desktop-version" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-container">
      <h3 class="title1">PERFUME</h3>
      <h2 class="title2"><b>Gavrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</b></h2>
      <p class="description-text">
        A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
      </p>
      <div class="both-prices">
        <h2 class="new-price">$149.99</h2>
        <h4 class="old-price">$169.99</h4>
      </div>
      <a class="cart-btn" href="#"><span></span>Add to cart</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that each of the elements inside of your `<tr>` have a default margin, creating that additional space you do not want [(illustrated here in yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHUAR.png).

Here are two options:

**Option 1:**
Recursively select all child elements of your `text-container` class and set the margin to 0:
Reference: [How to Select All Child Elements Recursively in CSS](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css.html)

```css
.text-container > * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**Option 2:** Create an additional CSS class that removes the margin from each element and apply as needed. For example:

```css
.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title1 no-margin">PERFUME</h3>
```

A helpful tool for debugging this sort of problem is the browser's developer tools. Check out this link that describes debugging in Google Chrome. [Chrome View and change CSS](https://View%20and%20change%20CSS). Other browsers have very similar tools.